# load spinner from text file android

Tags: android, spinner, text-files, fill

i'm working on a project to fill spinner from text file in assets or sdcard. My code is

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("product.txt"));

        String line = in.readLine();
        int index = 0;
        while (line != null) {

            str[index++] = line;
            line = in.readLine();
        }

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and main.xml

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting data from file?

Comment: yeah, the file is in assets folder, product.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is in the assets folder of you project, I think you have to do:

```
Vector<String>str=new Vector<String>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("product.txt"));

    String line = in.readLine();
    int index = 0;
    while (line != null) {

        str.add(line);
        line = in.readLine();
    }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then you have to right click on the assets directory in Eclipse then choose Build Path -> Use as Source Folder.

Comment: 2. might be the fault, tried to initialize like that Vector<String> str, but it gives me error

Comment: If now you are using the Vector class, you have to do: `Vector<String>str=new Vector<String>();` and then `str.add(line);`. What is the complete path of the file you want to read?

Comment: i want to read the file, no matter from where it can, rite now file is in assets folder

Comment: if i want to read that file from sdcard then path will change to?

Comment: Yes. Actually I haven't understood what you are trying to do, but if you have to read the file from the sdcard, you can use your previous code, but you have to give it the correct path

Comment: i want to call a file, product.txt, after calling user can make changes in it, the next question arise now!!!

Comment: You have to save it on the sdcard, so you can modify it runtime. See [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42), it may be useful.